# How to insert an element to a Fibonacci tree?

Tags: fibonacci, fibonacci-heap

Q. How would you insert an element to a Fibonacci tree.
I was thinking, because fibonacci trees are like sorted tree. I have to either balance the right tree or the left tree. but how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.  Fibonacci trees have a very precise shape, and you can't just add a new node in.  Did you mean a Fibonacci heap?

Answer (score 0):

### **Insert(Q, e)**

```
/* Insert the element e into the relaxed Fibonacci heap Q */
1.Form a tree with a single node N of type I consisting of element e
2. Add(Q, N)
3. With each node N of type I we associate a ﬁeld lost which denotes the
number of children of type I lost by N since its lost ﬁeld was last reset to
zero.
For any node N of type I in Q, deﬁne WN as the weight of node N as
follows: WN = 0, if N:lost = 0. Else, WN = 2
N:lost¡1
.
Also for any node N of type I, deﬁne wN as the increase in WN due to N
losing its last child. That is, wN = 0 or 1 or 2
N:lost¡2
respectively depending
on whether N:lost = 0 or 1 or greater than one.
Deﬁne weight W =
P
WN for all N of type I in Q.
Every relaxed Fibonacci heap has a special variable P, which is equal to
one of the nodes of the tree. Initially, P = R.
(a) R:lost = R0:lost = R1:lost = ::: = Rk¡1:lost = 0.
(b) Let N be any node of type I. Let N:degree = d and let the children
of N of type I be N0, N1, ..., Nd¡1. Then, for any Ni
, Ni
:degree +
Ni
:lost ¸ i.
(c) W · n + wP .
4. Associated with Q we have a list LM = (M1; M2; :::; Mm) of all nodes of
type II in Q other than R0
. Each node Mi was originally the R0
of some
relaxed Fibonacci heap Qi till some meld operation. Let ni denote the
number of nodes in Qi
just before that meld operation.
(a) Mi
:degree · 4dlog nie + 4.
(b) ni + i · n
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Where did you find this?  Can you cite your source?  Or at least show how a relaxed Fibonacci heap is related to a Fibonacci tree?

Comment: @templatetypedef..[see here](http://pmg.csail.mit.edu/~chandra/publications/heap.pdf) it may help you, if possible please upvote my answer